# Name of the function's property $f(\lambda u, v)=\lambda f(u,v)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

is there a specific name for the property of a function that satisfies:

$f(\lambda u, v)=\lambda f(u,v)$

where $\lambda$ is a scalar and $u, v$ are vectors of a vector space $V$?

I looked at the homogeneous functions, but if I understood it correctly, a function is homogeneous iff $\lambda$ is applied to both arguments:

$f(\lambda u, \lambda v)=\lambda^{k} f(u,v)$

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function))

Can a function be "partially" homogeneous?

Thank you

Duccio

Comment: I will call the function Homogeneous of degree 1 in the variable $u$

Comment: @BrunoB "linear in the first variable" would also require the additivity property $f(u+w,v)=f(u,v)+f(w,v)$ which is not assumed here.

Comment: @blargoner Right... I'm too used to my linear operators.